# how to import excel data to mysql relational table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have developed project in laravel for accounting related activity which has many relational tables with foreign keys in mysql. Everything works fine but the problem is my client has an excel file which has more than 10000 (ten thousand) records like vendor name,invoice number,date,amount etc..

So how can i import all of this data in mysql table? Client already have some tables like vendor name etc,so i've to assign all of the ids to existing invoice records! without doing this,my project will be useless. please help me..

Comment: You might want to consider using https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet to read the Excel data.

Comment: @nosurs sir,can you please tell me how can i use this

Comment: See https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-files/ for examples on how to read Excel files after you've [installed](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation) the library.

Comment: @nosurs okay sir,i'll check it. thanks